# Defining Schemas with Struct and Array Types

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe that has a schema (I read it and inferred) as such:

```
record_id           string
record_type         string
record_timestamp    string
checked             boolean
comments            bigint
categories          array<string>
geo                 struct<coordinates:array<double>,type:string>
```

Going forward I want to define the schema upfront as opposed to inferring it. I know how to define everything other than arrays and structs. For instance, if it was only the first five it would look like:

```
schema = StructType([\
    StructField(record_id, StringType(), True), \
    StructField(record_type, StringType(), True), \
    StructField(record_timestamp, TimestampType(), True), \
    StructField(checked, BooleanType(), True), \
    StructField(comments, LongType(), True) \
    ])
```

I cannot figure out how to define arrays and structs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, ArrayType, FloatType

zipsSchema3 = StructType([ \
  StructField("city", StringType(), True), \
  StructField("loc", \
    ArrayType(FloatType(), True), True), \
  StructField("pop", IntegerType(), True) \
])
```

Apply the schema to JSON means using the .schema method. This results in only the columns specified in the schema being returned and possibly changing the column types.

`loc` means an array of primitive types:
e.g. `"loc" : [ -72.576142, 42.176443 ]`

Here is a more complicated example with array with multiple fields:

```
fullTweetSchema = StructType([
  StructField("id", LongType(), True),
  StructField("user", StructType([
    StructField("id", LongType(), True),
    StructField("screen_name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("location", StringType(), True),
    StructField("friends_count", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("followers_count", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("description", StringType(), True)
  ]), True),
  StructField("entities", StructType([
    StructField("hashtags", ArrayType(
      StructType([
        StructField("text", StringType(), True)
      ]),
    ), True),
    StructField("urls", ArrayType(
      StructType([
        StructField("url", StringType(), True),
        StructField("expanded_url", StringType(), True),
        StructField("display_url", StringType(), True)
      ]),
    ), True)
  ]), True),
  StructField("lang", StringType(), True),
  StructField("text", StringType(), True),
  StructField("created_at", StringType(), True)
])
```